# Adding data field to pivot table in python

Tags: python, excel

I found a python code to create pivot tables in Excel [here](http://pythonexcels.com/automating-pivot-tables-with-python/). And this is how values are added to the data field:

```
wb.ActiveSheet.PivotTables(tname).AddDataField(
    wb.ActiveSheet.PivotTables(tname).PivotFields(sumvalue[7:]),
    sumvalue,
    win32c.xlSum)
```

What do the parameters mean? I need to modify them to suit my application. Please help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured that out. `wb.ActiveSheet.PivotTables(tname).PivotFields(sumvalue[7:])` is the object of the python field you want to add as the data field. `sumvalue[7:]` can be any field name. `sumvalue` is the title that will show at the top of your pivot table. I believe win32.xlsum  is the function that Excel calls (you can see it when you generate a macro in Excel).